# What does Pokémon Appraisal actually tell you in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The new update to Pokémon go brought Pokémon Appraisal to the game. The information it tells you I'm still trying to decipher.

For example, when I apraise my strongest Pokémon a 1500 CP Vaporeon, I get the following information:

> Overall, your Rainer is a wonder! What a breathtaking Pokémon!
>
> I see that its best attribute is its Attack.
>
> Its stats exceed my calculations. It's incredible.
>
> Your Rainer is tinier than any we have on record. Astounding.

The first line seems like just filler and the last line is already denoted by the size markings on my Vaporeon. I get the general idea that it is statistically strong and it has good attack from lines 2 and 3, but does it mean that the attack IV is perfect?

How exactly do you relate the appraisal to your Pokémon's stats?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depending on your team, the leaders say different things.  This handy chart will help you determine what they're actually saying.

[image: Gym leader explanations for appraisals]

Answer (score 18):

Appraisals are explained in depth [here](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-appraisal).

---

For your particular example, it means the following:

> Overall, your Rainer is a wonder! What a breathtaking Pokémon!

This Pokemon's Individual Values (IVs) are at the top end (82.2%-100%)

> I see that its best attribute is its Attack.

This means the Pokemon will do more damage with its moves than Vaporeons with lower Attack.

> Its stats exceed my calculations. It's incredible.

Pokemon has perfect IVs in at least one base stat.

> Your Rainer is tinier than any we have on record. Astounding.

Your Pokemon is small size.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this myself yet, but it looks like an in-game IV-rater, much like the normal series provides in the form of a "Pokemon Rater" person you can find somewhere in the world.

First Line: Overall IV rating, average Attack, Defense, and Stamina.
Second Line: Highest IV stat.
Third Line: Possibly an indication of how good the stat mentioned in the second line is. (You know Attack is highest, but is it good, great, bad, etc)
Fourth Line: Based on size, weight/height, which you are right, you can see in the pokemon info page.

As we see it more, we'll be able to determine what phrase is used for what ranged of IV values. This is most likely been implemented so we don't need to use third-party IV calculators like the one found at https://thesilphroad.com/research.

Answer (score -1):

In simple words - **Pokemon Appraisals give you hint about your Pokemon IVs and power, and how well is it suited for gyms battles**. The better appraisals, the more likely you should be to use that Pokemon for Gym battles.