# How does the Appraise feature's results correlate with IVs?

Tags: pokemon-go

Version 1.5.0 brought the new **Appraise** feature to Pokemon GO, as an added option in the menu button on individual pokémon:

> #### What's New in Version 1.5.0 <sub><sup>Posted August 23, 2016</sup></sub>
>
> - Implemented Pokémon Appraisal: Trainers will now be able to learn about a Pokémon's attack and defense capabilities from their Team Leader (Candela, Blanche, or Spark) to determine which of their Pokémon have the most potential for battle.

The output of using it on a particular pokémon *seems* to be referencing what we've come to know as [Individual Values (IVs)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276692/in-pokemon-go-what-are-my-pokemons-hidden-iv-stats-and-why-do-they-matter). Do these descriptive phrases represent IVs, and if so how accurately do these correlate to specific IV numbers?

Put another way, how useful is the new Appraise feature as a replacement for IV calculators?

Comment: Similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283049/what-does-pok%C3%A9mon-appraisal-actually-tell-you-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go

Comment: @Dom I think that's actually a duplicate. Thanks! That question couldn't be found by typing the name of the menu option (“Appraise”), so having a duplicate that can be will help searches find the answer.