# Can I tell the IVs of a pokemon by information provided from the Detailscreen?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am aiming to have perfect Pokémon so I don't care about Stardust-Cost or any other investment - other than time.

Having over 300 Pokémon in my bag, I was wondering whether there is a way to estimate IVs without using the appraisal-feature or 3rd party programms? 

For example: Is it possible for perfect IV Pokemons to have 10CP?

Comment: You have to realize even perfect pidgeys are pretty useless, so you can just throw them all away.  They're good for evolving to get EXP.

Comment: Now that I reduced my level of frustration, I edited the question to be more specific and less salty.

Answer (score 0):

A level 0 pokemon with IVs of 0/0/0 is indistinguishable from one with IVs of 15/15/15. If you are using an IV rater you'll need to level it up at least once to be able to gauge it's IVs.

However, for your situation, just appraise your pokemon... If they don't say that all three stats are the pokemon's best stat, it's not perfect. Check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283049/what-does-pok%C3%A9mon-appraisal-actually-tell-you-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go) for a more in depth guide to interpreting the appraisal.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to appraise them. Some pokemon (pidgey) at level 0 are 10cp/10hp with 0/0/0 IV and 15/15/15 IV. Other pokemon (dratini) at level 0 are 10cp/10hp with 0/0/0 IV and 13cp/10hp with 15/15/15 IVs. For pokemon that are 10cp/10hp regardless of IVs, they have to be appraised. For pokemon that are not, you could try and memorize the "high" cp number for a given level.

Personally, I don't think level 0 pidgeys are worth keeping, even at 15/15/15. Too much stardust/candy to get anything out of it.

Comment: The CP formula is MAX(10, X) where X involves all the stats.  Hence, 10 CP tells you very little and may include 0/0/0 or 15/15/15.  Appraisal is fastest and simplest.  Side note: I think pokemon start at level 1.